# Is it possible expand stroke in Photoshop or make stroke resize along the shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, stroke

When I resize a shape in Photoshop CS6, its stroke's width remains the same size as it was in its original width. It could be desirable depending on a situation, but most of the time it's not. In fact, it beats the purpose of vector; same shape/look at all sizes.

In illustrator you can expand the stroke so this problem doesn't happen.

So is there a way to make stroke's width dependent on the size of the shape?

Answer (score 1):

The only other way as of now to simulate the behavior is to convert the shape into smart object.

As you can see here:
[In Photoshop, is there a way to incorporate a stroke into the shape object/layer itself?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2332/in-photoshop-is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-a-stroke-into-the-shape-object-layer)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the image size, the stroke and shape is also increased proportional to the size also we can keep the quality..Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

No. The vector strokes are set and will not scale when dragging a vector shape. There is no way to change this behavior in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

convert the stroke layer to smart object and it will keep its thickness as vector shape

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found a way! Here it is)) all effects and strokes are scaled

Comment: what dialog is that. i dont understand russian

Comment: image resize?... won't that change everything. but i guess for full page it's one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in Photoshop, but you can

1. Save your shape as Photoshop .eps. The eps format will outline the strokes.
2. Open that .eps in illustrator
3. Grab the shapes and copy/paste them into Photoshop as vector shape

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2-29EHRRHA&t=2s